# Is Morse theory local?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, morse-theory, persistent-homology

I am currently trying to use Morse theory in my work. Say I have $X$ smooth compact manifold and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function. The classical result I know is : when $f$ has non-degenerate critical points such that every level set $f^{-1}(\{ c \})$ contains at most one critical point, then $X$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex.

What if there are several critical points in a sublevel set $f^{-1}(\{ c \})$ ? It seems to me that it shouldn't change the result.
Moreover, if we were to look at the persistent homology of $c \mapsto X \cap f^{-1}(]-\infty, c])$, the topological features born/disappearing at $c$ should be independent. My first question would be : is it the case ?

More precisely, I wanted to formalise it the following way : say we know of $\mathcal{U}_i, i \in \{ 1, \dots k \}$ a finite open covering of $X$ such that the CW-homotopy type of $\mathcal{U_i} \cap X \cap f^{-1}(] - \infty , c])$ is known when $c$ varies.
My second question would be : How do I extract the CW-complex homotopy type of $X \cap f^{-1}(] \infty, c])$ for every $c$ ? Should I have more assumptions on the $\mathcal{U}_i$ ?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes.

Comment: Even in the first question you have to be careful about what you mean by "independent". Example: $M$ is a circle, and $f$ has two minima and two maxima. A zero-dimensional homology class disappears at one maximum and then a one-dimensional homology class appears at the other maximum. But if the two maxima occur at one level how do you think about this?

Comment: Do you have any reference on this @BenMcKay ? 

By "independent" I mean that the number of feature changes at $c$, i.e number of bars modified in the persistent barcode of $X \cap f^{-1}(] -\infty, c])$, is exactly the number of points in $f^{-1}(\{ c \})$. This applies to your example.

Comment: In a Morse chart, add a small bump function to alter the height of the Morse function, not changing the criticality by symmetry, and not changing the nondegeneracy, because it is multiplied by so small a factor. Then you can move all critical points to their own critical value. This is covered in many Morse theory books. But the picture remains homeomorphic near each point, as the ascending and descending cells are the same points in the Morse chart.